# Rotation of plane wave spinor versus plane wave spinor with rotated momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, spinors

Suppose I have a massless fermion with momentum $p^\mu = (E,\, E\cos\theta,\, 0,\, E\sin\theta)$. There are two ways to write the plane wave spinor $u(p)$ with respect to the spin $\xi$, and I seem to find different answers:

1. Plug the momentum into (e.g. Peskin (3.50))
   $$u(p) = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\,\xi\\ \sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}\,\xi \end{pmatrix}$$
   For small $\theta$ and $\xi = (1,0)$, this gives:
   $$u(p) = 
   \sqrt{2E}
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
   \theta/2\\
   1\\
   \theta/2
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   For $\theta\to 0$ this matches the expected result for a massless plane wave spinor along the $z$-direction.
2. Alternatively, we may start with a massless plane wave spinor along the $z$ direction, $u(k)$ with $k^\mu = (E, \, 0, \, 0, \, E)$. We can then rotate this spinor with the appropriate representation of the Lorentz transformation (Peskin (3.27) and (3.30)). Taking again the case $\xi=(1,0)$:
   $$
   u(p) 
   = \Lambda_{\frac 12}(\omega) u(k) \,
   = e^{-\frac i2 \omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}} \,
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
   0\\
   \sqrt{2E}\\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
   \sqrt{2E}
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
   0\\
   1\\
   \theta/2
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

**I am puzzled why the two approaches give different answers.**

For a massless fermion, I expected the $\xi = (1,0)$ state to stay in the lower-two components of a Dirac spinor (using Peskin's conventions) because chirality should be preserved. Why should plugging in a momentum $p^\mu$ that is slightly rotated from $(E,0,0,E)$ lead to an opposite chirality component in the first approach?

Am I perhaps confused about helicity being measured with respect to the $z$-direction versus with respect to the direction of motion?

### Intermediate Steps

In the first approach, I use the following expressions:
$$
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}
=\sqrt{\frac E2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-c_\theta & -s_\theta\\
-s_\theta & 1+c_\theta
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} p\cdot\sigma
\\
\sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}
=\sqrt{\frac E2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+c_\theta & s_\theta\\
s_\theta & 1-c_\theta
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} p\cdot\bar\sigma
$$
where $c_\theta \equiv \cos\theta$ and $s_\theta \equiv \sin\theta$. In the small $\theta$ limit this gives:
$$
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}
=\sqrt{\frac E2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\theta\\
-\theta & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}
=\sqrt{\frac E2}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & \theta\\
\theta & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For the second approach, the transformation parameter is $\omega_{13}=-\omega_{31} = - \theta$ which multiplies the generator
$$
S^{13} = -\frac 12 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2 &\\ 
& \sigma^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that the rotation matrix is
$$
\Lambda_{\frac 12} =
e^{-\frac i2 \omega_{13}S^{13} - \frac i2 \omega_{31}S^{31}}
=
\exp\left[-\frac{i\theta}{2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2 &\\
&\sigma^2
\end{pmatrix}\right]
=
\mathbb{1}+\frac{\theta}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0& -1 && \\
1 &0&&\\
&&0&-1\\
&&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From these two intermediate steps the puzzle is clear: plugging in $\xi = (1,0)$ in the first method gives three non-zero components. In the second method, this corresponds to $u(k)=(0,0,1,0)$ and we see that $\Lambda_{\frac 12} u(k)$ has only two non-zero components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that in the first method, $\xi = (1,0)$ is no longer a state of definite helicity. This is because $\xi=(1,0)$ is a state of definite spin in the $z$-direction, whereas the helicity is defined to be the spin along the direction of motion:
$$
h(\mathbf{p})\equiv \frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot\sigma}{|\mathbf{p}|}
$$
where $\mathbf{p}$ is the 3-momentum, in contrast to the 4-momentum $p$.

Let us write
$$u_\xi(p) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\xi\\
\sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}\xi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Rather than $\xi = (1,0)$, we should use the eigenvector of $h(\mathbf{p})$ that equals $(1,0)$ in the limit where $\mathbf{p} = (0,0,E)$. This is
$$
\xi_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{1+c_\theta}\\
\sqrt{1-c_\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\ ,
$$
where $c_\theta = \cos\theta$ and $\mathbf{p} = (E\sin\theta,\,0\,,E\cos\theta)$. Upon plugging this in, one finds
$$
u_{\xi_+}(p) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\xi_+\\
\sqrt{p\cdot\bar\sigma}\xi_+
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\sqrt{2E}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\theta/2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which indeed matches the result of the second method.

Note that no adjustment was necessary for the second method: you started with a plane wave spinor moving along the $z$-direction so the helicity is aligned with the quantization axis. If you start with a state of definite helicity, applying $\Lambda_{1/2}$, one rotates the entire plane wave, but it is still a state of the same definite helicity.